# Getting Auth Results in Laravel Custom Console Command

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, scaffolding

I am making a console command which I want to schedule. I have written the complete code which I wanted but the issue I am facing is that in custom console command when I write:

```
Auth::user();
```

It returns:

> null

This command is not going to execute into my application due to which it is giving:

> null

I get that but then I made a static function inside one of my model and returns the id from there to my console command handle function still it is giving me **Null** any idea on how can I get Auth record in my custom laravel console command. Any help would be great.

**Edit:**
Here is the static method I wrote to get the id.

```
public static function getAuhtCode(){
    $code = Auth::user()->id;
    return $code;
}
```

Comment: Which authentication guard do you use?

Comment: Guard is Web and driver is session.

Comment: What is that command supposed to do? What if more than one user is auth'd on your app?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `loginUsingId` method from session guard to manually authenticate a user thanks to an id.

```php
/**
     * Log the given user ID into the application.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $id
     * @param  bool  $remember
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|false
     */
    public function loginUsingId($id, $remember = false)
    {
        if (! is_null($user = $this->provider->retrieveById($id))) {
            $this->login($user, $remember);

            return $user;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

For example

```php
Auth::loginUsingId(1);
Auth::user(); //Will work
```

Comment: Again the id 1 will be static  I want to get the logged in user id.

Comment: Just replace my `1` but your static method call

Comment: But my static method returns null

Comment: Then share your static method

Comment: I have edited my question please check my statis method

Comment: You can't make this method work in an Artisan command context unless manually authenticating someone

Comment: Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::$provider error how to fix it?